# TemplateBeginRepeat in reverse order

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am need to create 2 loops using `TemplateBeginRepeat` where I need to output custom tags

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="customtag" -->
    ${RenderComponentPresentation(Field, rendercustomtagstarttemplate)}
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Output some html

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="customtag" -->
    ${RenderComponentPresentation(Field, rendercustomtagclosetemplate)}
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Since the second loop closes the custom tag rendered by the first loop, the second loop should run in reverse order. (since tags need to be closed in reverse order). How do i run the second loop in reverse order of components with TemplateBeginRepeat?

Comment: What type is `customtag`? Is it a field?

Comment: Be aware that ${} should only be used for exceptions, and not by default. It allows you to evaluate (render) the expressions first, prior to the default @@ @@.

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in way to loop over the repeated items in a reverse order.

---

If your `customtag` is an array item (typically an array of Components or Component Presentations) in the package, you can push a list into the package that contains the same items in reverse order and then loop over that item.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="customtag_reversed" -->
```

---

If your `customtag` is a field, this will not work, since you cannot push a field into the package. In that case I suggest creating a custom function that outputs your custom tags in the correct order, e.g.:

```
@@RenderCustomTags('customtag', 'Order.Reverse')@@
```

---

**Update**

If `customtag` is a **Component Link** field, it's better to simply add those linked Components to the package as a Component Array item. Nuno provided a link to a TBB on SDL Tridion World, but this is the most critical fragment:

```
//  Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.ComponentPresentation
var list = new List<ComponentPresentation>(); 

list.Add(new ComponentPresentation(Component.Id, ComponentTemplate.Id));
// you'll want to do a loop of these for every linked Component

var item = package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.ComponentArray,
                                    ComponentPresentationList.ToXml(list));
package.PushItem("customtag_Components", item);
```

You'll want to do a loop of these for every linked Component:

```
list.Add(new ComponentPresentation(Component.Id, ComponentTemplate.Id));
```

And instead of hard-coding the Component Template ID in the C# code, you can also consider leaving it empty in C# and keeping it inside the `RenderComponentPresentation` call in your DWT like you already do.

Comment: Frank, customtag is a multi-valued Component Link metadata field

Comment: So it's a field. You'll have to create your own collection then (create ComponentArray in c#, push to package with reverse order). Example here http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/useful_tbbs.aspx - check the "Group Components By Template Type" TBB or "Get Sibling Components")

Comment: You're right Nuno, pushing the linked Components into the package will probably work better in this case. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here seems to be that Dreamweaver syntax is only suitable for the simplest programming tasks. Frank and Nuno have shown that moving *some* of the logic to a C# template gives an improvement, but you should also consider moving the generation of this output *entirely* to the C# template. In other words, once you get to the point of needing to use something other than DWT, your problem definition changes, because the problem as now described is very DWT-centric.

The need to loop in reverse only exists because you want to close your constructs in the correct order. In a language like C# you could achieve this result by using nested (even recursive) function calls, or (perhaps more likely) by pushing your closing output to a stack.

Comment: Agreed Dom. And given the call to `RenderComponentPresentation` here, which is likely to generate the majority of the HTML, the C# to handle the look would probably not be outputting much HTML (maybe just a `ul` and `li`s). If you're attached to being able to modify the source later without requiring Visual Studio, I'd suggest a C# fragment TBB as an alternative to tricky constructs in the DWT.

Comment: What happens if a DWT calls the template it's in? :-) Frank, I don't see lists, though. This feels more like a nesting of whatever-nodes-the-author wants: `<div><p><span> rest of the content </span></p></div>', where div, p, and span are the `customtag` fields. So maybe C# just outputs angle brackets and attributes? Hopefully this component is for devs or power users.